# simple login ajax check

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a little piece of code that i need someone to offer me some help to identify where the mistake I am making. I am thankful for any help you offered.

```
     $('#username').change(function()
     {
        $.ajax(
        {
           type:"POST",
           url:'login.php'
           //datatype:'html'
        }
        ).done(function(data)
        {
           $('#info').html(data);
        }
        );
     });
```

My login.php includes use of mysqli function to connect to db and check if the user already exists blah blah blah.

```
function query($query)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root', 'okazaki', 'gene_database');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    } 

    if($result=$mysqli->query($query))
    {
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        $mysqli->close();
        print_r($data);
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unable to query data");
        $mysqli->close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're seeing? Any errors?

Comment: which object has id username,post your html syntax

Comment: where is the call for this function in your script ?

Answer (score 0):

`echo $data` instead of returning it, `return` doesn't output anything, it simply returns it (at server level)

(edit: sorry missed the `print_r` in your question)

Where is your `query` function being called? In the example you've posted it isn't. You could add another property to your ajax request, such as `action: 'checkUser'` or something similar, and then in `login.php` check if `$_POST['action']` is `checkUser`, if it is, then run the `query` function.

Also, you're not actually sending any data to check in your ajax request, looking at your example you should be sending the value of username (`$('#username').val()`) in order to build the `$query` to pass to your `query` function.

Hope that points you in the right direction.